# How to make an apple watch effect with scroll for website?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make effect an apple watch my website with CSS + JS. 
I have a screenshot, how it should look like.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0JRL.png)

I will be grateful for the help

Comment: How have you researched, and what have you tried?  Sounds like more of a "request for free coding services" than a question.  Can you give some more info?  See: [ask]

Comment: I am sorry, my English not very well. I meant someone had faced such a task, point to the instruction.

Comment: https://github.com/Dzinlife/Apple-Watch-Spring-Board - I found a solution, but here I can not understand how to make indentation between elements as in design.